# Convert class to another class and vice versa

Tags: c#, design-patterns, asp.net-mvc

I've a domain class named Campaign.

```
Class Campaign {
    public long CampaignID { get; set; }
    public string CampaignName { get; set; }
    public DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

In addition to that, i'm using Asp.net MVC, and I defined a model class.

```
[DataContract]
public class CampaignModel
{
    [DataMember(Name="id")]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "name")]
    public string CampaignName { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "isDummy")]
    public bool IsDummy { get; set; }
}
```

My goal is to convert from one class to another and vice versa.

I'm using the ASP.NET for REST calls from my Angular 2 app.

My app has two use cases, one is to create Campaign, therefore I need to convert from CampaignModel to Campaign class and store the campaign.
The second use-case is to load existing Campaign into the UI, therefore convert from Campaign to CamapignModel.

- If that's matter, the conversation between the two isn't trivial and involves using complex data structures.

I've thought of several options:

1. Create two methods in the CampaignModel.

   ```
   public Campaign Convert();
   public CampaignModel Convert(Campaign);
   ```
2. Create separate class e.g. CampaignConverter
3. Use dedicated known library that facilitates the conversion between the two, or known design pattern?
4. any other ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You can use a T4 template to generate both classes and the conversion from a common source.

Comment: How are `IsDummy` of the model, `StartTime` and `EndTime` of the domain class expected to get their values during conversion? How to deal with converting and converting back?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is a simple cast job (it doesn't seem to be), I'd use an explicit operator. There are some nice examples in [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4.aspx) about this:

```
// Must be defined inside a class called Fahrenheit:
public static explicit operator Celsius(Fahrenheit fahr)
{
    return new Celsius((5.0f / 9.0f) * (fahr.degrees - 32));
}
```

This cast is done in the **client** class, the class that's the destination of the cast. The source doesn't have to know who's gonna consume it. It's a responsibility of the consumer to do the proper casting.

However, this part of your question got me thinking:

> If that's matter, the conversation between the two isn't trivial and involves using complex data structures.

If this transformation is complex, time-consuming, involves IO and prone to launch exceptions, then the best way is to create a specific class in a **Business** layer (or in your **Domain** layer), responsible to do the transformation and handle properly the possible exceptions.

But just be aware that a Data Contract should not be an inner part of your Domain model, because it's at the boundary. And "[At the Boundaries, Applications are Not Object-Oriented](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/31/AttheBoundaries,ApplicationsareNotObject-Oriented/)".

Comment: Thanks, I did go with the second option to create a new class that will deal with the transformation. Is there any naming convention for such a class? if there is can you please name one?

Comment: Aside from this: https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TwoHardThings.html , what is the class doing ? It converting what to what ?